# iOS image view: how can I implement this?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

As the photos put here, the image view has a placeholder as the same size as the image is downloading in the background, how can I implement this?

Comment: Sorry, i can't post the photos here. Can you understand my question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for this. It is the best Networking Library available for iOS. Even best apps like Facebook iOS app is using AFNetworking.

```
#import "UIImageview+AFNetworking.h"
```

After importing just use like this

```
[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.com"]
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]
                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                        imageView.image = image;


                                    } failure:nil];
```

Comment: I can't post a screenshot here, but I don't know if you understand what I meant. The placeholder's size is as the image still downloading background.(it haven't been downloaded) after the image is download, the image view'size is exactly the image's, it's in a cell.